# MS Access Report with static even page

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to do something that seems simple, but isn't.
I want to print invoices with the invoice details (customer info and records) only on odd pages and the 'sales conditions' on the even pages, since the document will be printed recto-verso.
Until now I've tried a bunch of things.
-setting detail not visible if page is even, works, but then of course I'll never see the records if they span more than one page.
-I've put page breaks in the detail section and made them visible or unvisible depending on the page being odd or even.
- created subreport in detail section and did everything I could imagine with it.

No avail....
I'm almost at the point that I will simply print to pdf the files and add in the pdf the sales conditions as even pages...

Anyone a solution in Access reports?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is that you print your orders info as is, and then you turn the face of the Paper, print another "Sales Conditions" Access Report/static World/Pdf on the back of all invoices pages.

All big businesses use the "2-Report" method for invoice, not only it's simple, but also it reduces CPU time during

```
report_open(), repoprt_format(), report_print(), ....
```

Beside, you must turn the face of a paper for the verso printing even if you integrate all in a single report, if you have only a common trademark Laser Printer, or Inkjet Printer.